# How to conditionally enable console without opening separate console window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console

I'd like to create a windows application that, under normal conditions, does not have any connected terminal, but may have one in some conditions. I tried two different routes. Option A, creating a normal console application, and conditionally calling `FreeConsole()`:

```
int main()
{
    if (someCondition) {
        HANDLE stdOutHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        WriteConsoleA(stdOutHandle, "hello world\n", 12, NULL, NULL);
    } else {
        FreeConsole();
        // normal operation
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And option B, creating a WinMain based application, and conditionally calling `AllocConsole()`.

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    if (someCondition) {
        AllocConsole();
        HANDLE stdOutHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        WriteConsoleA(stdOutHandle, "hello world\n", 12, NULL, NULL);
    }
    else {
        // normal operation
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The problem with option A, is that it doesn't act exactly like a windows application, in that you can very briefly see a console window open up before normal operation continues. This isn't a huge problem, but I'd prefer the program to act, as I said, exactly like a normal windows application.

The problem with option B is that, if the program is invoked from an existing terminal, it opens up a separate terminal window and outputs to that, instead of outputting to the terminal from which it was invoked. This is a much bigger problem.

What is the appropriate solution to conditionally behave as either a console program or a windows program, without either of the problems described above?

Edit

Based on a suggestion in the comments, I tried to use the `AttachConsole` function.

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    if (someCondition) {
        AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
        HANDLE stdOutHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);    
        Sleep(3000);
        WriteConsoleA(stdOutHandle, "hello world\n", 12, NULL, NULL);
        FreeConsole();
    }
    else {
        // normal operation
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

This seems to be on the right track, but there is still something missing, because my shell prompt is immediately printed out without waiting for the program to finish.

Comment: You should try AttachConsole. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/attachconsole

Comment: @engf-010: That almost works. But there's some other plumbing missing, because my shell prompt immediately prints out, without waiting for the program to finish.

Comment: if you're starting from the command line ,you can wait for it to finish (IIRC - it's been ages ). look for parameters for START (help START).

Comment: @engf-010: My goal is for this to require no special behavior on the part of the user. I'm starting to think this is not possible though, and that's why some programs have two separate versions, (e.g. 'python.exe' and 'pythonw.exe'). I'll probably just go with my original option A.

Comment: *Why* do you want a console window? What must be done in the console that can't be done in the GUI?

Comment: This question has been asked hundreds of times here. Invariably by people fighting the system. Don't fight the system!

Comment: *"my shell prompt is immediately printed out without waiting for the program to finish"* - That's just how the command interpreter works when it launches a Windows application. If you want the console to wait use the [`start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impossible.

`AttachConsole` does not work 100% because cmd.exe actually checks if the process it is about to start is a GUI app or not, and alters its behavior.

The only way to make it work is to have two programs; myapp.com and myapp.exe. %PathExt% lists .com before .exe so you can make a console .exe and rename it .com at it will be executed if the user runs "myapp" (but will not work if the user types "myapp.exe"). If your program is not very big you can just ship two versions. If the program is large you can move most of the code to a .dll or make the .com a small helper that calls the .exe with a command line parameter and some pipes for stdin/stdout. Visual Studio does this ([devenv.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches?view=vs-2022#devenv-switch-syntax)).

Comment: That's what I was beginning to suspect. Thanks.

Comment: Or do as python and java do and have python.exe and pythonw.exe targeting console and GUI sj systems.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if there is already a console, check for a NULL return from `GetConsoleWindow()`. If it returns null, then do the AllocConsole procedure and other setup (SetWindowLong, SetConsoleMode etc)

int main() programs don't make a console by default, they happen to attach into a console if run through cmd/ps.

Comment: *"If you want to check if there is already a console"* -- I don't. That's not what my question is about. *"int main() programs don't make a console by default"* -- Yes, they do. If you have a main function, and not a WinMain function, the compiler detects this and forwards the `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` flag to the linker. But that's neither here nor there.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Okay, so I tried it out, and for short-running apps the console isn't always visible when int main is used, my bad -
I think you should not use AllocConsole if you don't want to make a new window, GetConsoleWindow should return you a window handle for the current console so you don't need to make an extra

Comment: If I call `GetConsoleWindow()` from a windows application without having first called `AllocConsole()`, it returns NULL, even when I invoke the program from a terminal.

Comment: I'm guessing that `AllocConsole()` is probably not the function I want. It was just what I tried based on perusing Microsoft documentation. Whatever function or sequence of functions I should be calling instead, in order to get access to the terminal from which the program was invoked, that's what I'm asking about.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I think AttachConsole is what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

One way is the following:

```
BOOL WINAPI
AttachOrCreateConsole()
{
    if(AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return AllocConsole();
}
```

This will use the parent console if available and fall back to creating one if needed.

Note that if yo do this and want to use the standard C/C++ I/O mechanisms (stdin/std::cin, stdout/std::cout) you will need to do the work needed to associate those streams to the console handle. There is plenty of material available on how to do that.